# Change text with jquery and get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

What is wrong with my javascript/jquery code?

```
<%= link_to 'Click', '#', id: 'link' %><span id="new-data"></span>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $("#link").click(function(){
    $.get('http://httpbin.org/get', { name: "John", time: "2pm" }).done(function(data) {
            $("#new-data").text(data);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: what error do you see ?

Comment: `console.log(data);` to see what you're getting back as a response.

Comment: I don't get any error. Console.log shows the correct response but the text of #new-data doesn't change

Comment: Use firefox console and I think you will figure it out yourself!

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).on("click","#link",function(){
    $.get('http://httpbin.org/get', { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function(data) {
            $("#new-data").html(data);
    });
});
```

The response held in `data` must be in the immediate callback, not in the `.done()` callback, which only executes on success and does not contain the response at all.

Comment: `The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callback methods introduced in jQuery 1.5 are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.`. From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: The text still does not change. Console shows the response is correct but the #newdata.text is not displayed/changed

Comment: @Khanh TO - Yes, but `.done()` does not contain the response, only the immediate callback within the `$.get` method holds the response.

Comment: Check the example at the end of the page: `Alert the results from requesting test.cgi with an additional payload of data (HTML or XML, depending on what was returned).`

Comment: @spuggy, try it with `.html()` method instead of `.text()`.

Comment: .html still didn't change the text :(Heres the console data  
200 OK
  578ms 
jquery.min.js (line 5)
GET http://httpbin.org/get?name=John&time=2pm
 
200 OK
  333ms 
jquery.min.js (line 5)

Comment: That doesn't show us what the response is. Please copy/paste what is being logged to the console when you insert `console.log(data);` before `$("#new-data").text(data);`.

Comment: This issue clearly doesn't require two people to solve so I'll let the Wrath of Khan take over... good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you're using absolute Urls. Some browsers treat absolute Urls as cross-domain requests even if it's not. Try using relative urls instead.

```
$("#link").click(function(){
    $.get('/get', { name: "John", time: "2pm" }).done(function(data) {
            $("#new-data").text(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Im getting the response ok as shown in console but the #newdata.text is not displayed/changed

Comment: @spuggy: you should change it to relative urls if possible. That's better because some browsers have problems with absolute urls. This is another suggestion to improve your code.

Comment: @spuggy: how did you check it? You used network capture or used `console.log(data)`

Comment: @spuggy: your original code should work, just need to change it to relative urls to avoid problems with some browsers.

Comment: $(document).on("click","#link",function(){
    $.get('http://httpbin.org/get', { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function(data) {
            $("#new-data").html(data);
            console.log(data);
    });
});</script> and then went to firebug console. ok?

Comment: @spuggy: if `console.log(data)` shows correctly but you still have empty in your `$("#new-data").text(data);`. The only problem I can think of is the id (new-data) is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work : reference from jquery doc, please find it [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

```
<script>

$("#link").click(function() {
 $.get("http://httpbin.org/get", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function  (data) {
    $("#new-data").text(data);
  });
}

</script>
```